# Azure Event Hubs - ImportError: No module named eventhubs

Tags: python, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

I am trying to use the [Python Event Hubs SDK](https://github.com/azure/azure-event-hubs-python) on Ubuntu, but when I try to import the `eventhubs` module, I get:

> ImportError: No module named eventhubs

As recommended, I installed Proton-C and all the needed dependencies:

> libs: libxml2-dev, libxslt-dev, libffi-dev, python3-cffi
>   Python packages: requests, bs4, lxml, azure-storage, azure-storage-blob

I tried to install through the possible modules names:

```
pip install azure-event-hubs-sdk
pip install azure-event-hubs
pip install azure-event-hubs-python
pip install azure-eventhubs
```

But, still nothing.

Comment: Do you use python 2 or 3?

Comment: Python 2, @Rita . But I was informed by a member of Azure developers that the python sdk is not working as it should.